# When zooming in and out in flutter web it resize the image and deformating it

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, flutter-image

I was building a menu web app for a bussiness. I imported the images to project and tried to resize them on website but they didnt resize as i expected. I want them to stick eachother and when i zoom in or out i dont want them to move away from each other. but now when i zoom in-out, the distance between each other decreases and increases, they are not fixed.
**I DONT WANT TO DİSABLE ZOOM IN/OUT. I WANT TO LEARN HOW TO CONFIGURE IMAGES ON WEBSİTE FOR ZOOMİNG NOT FOR THIS PROJECT BUT MAYBE FOR ANOTHER.**

Issue video: https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/folders/1ibH6EgHEFajeFD9cilcI6SeGIPVPKCQU

```
  Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 194, 164, 31),
      body: GridView.count(
        crossAxisCount: 1,
        mainAxisSpacing: 10,
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            child: Image.asset('assets/1.png'),
          ),
          Container(
            child: Image.asset('assets/2.png'),
          ),
          Container(
            child: Image.asset('assets/3.png'),
          ),
          Container(
            child: Image.asset('assets/4.png'),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is GridView widget's layouting. I've used ListView instead of GridView and problem solved. Because ListView layouts each widget one after another and then you can put a distance between them. So use ListView...